# OR inside an AND is only evaluating one of the OR conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

right now I have a query similar to

```
SELECT
   table1.column1,
   table2.column2,
   table1.column3
FROM
   table1
   table2
WHERE
   table1.column3 > SYSDATE
   AND ((table1.column1 = 'STRING1') OR (table2.column2 LIKE 'STRING2'))
```

This query is only returning records that meet:

```
table2.column2 LIKE 'STRING2'
```

where as it should be returning values that fail to meet that condition but still meet:

```
table1.column1 = 'STRING1'
```

Is my logic messed up, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Without data, we can't say. Consider posting sample data with expected results and actual results. Or better yet, setup a [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: Excluding the previous condition, that will return all rows that meet *either* the `column1 = 'STRING1'` **or** the `column2 LIKE 'STRING2'` conditions. Thus either the columns are wrong, the expected output is wrong, or the data is not as expected (including possible exclusion by `table1.column3 > SYSDATE`) . Use each expression separately, one at a time,to determine which expression "doesn't work"; because the OR operator works fine.

Comment: Thanks user2864740! I separated each condition separately and it seemed there was something wrong with the `= 'STRING1'` part; even though column2 was returning STRING1, I tried using a LIKE '%STRING1%' and for some reason that seemed to fix the issue. Feel free to post your comment as an answer so I can select it.

Comment: @Nickknack Check for extra spaces at the end (or the start) of the column data in question. Ending spaces might have been brought over accidentally if the column is a VARCHAR.

Comment: there is no join condition between table1 and table2

Comment: Agreed with @Eng.SamerT - this is a cartesian join so the logic is suspect.

Comment: I left out the rest of the where's because they seemed irrelevant; i won't next time. Regardless user2864740's comment put me on the right track. Thanks for all the input, it's  much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your explanation correctly:

```
WHERE
   table1.column3 > SYSDATE
   AND ((table1.column1 = 'STRING1') AND (table2.column2 NOT LIKE 'STRING2'))
```